# The relation $<$ is not definable in structure $\langle\mathbb R,+,0\rangle$ as a first order formula

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

the question is:

> The relation $<$ is not definable in structure $\langle\mathbb R,+,0\rangle$ with a first order formula.

I asked my professor for help and he told me to consider $\langle\mathbb R,+,0\rangle$ as a vector space and work on its automorphism.

But even now I can't solve this problem...

Can someone please give me some help to understand the clue?

And also why I can't instead prove: the relation $<$ is not definable in the structure $\langle\mathbb N,+,0\rangle$ as a first order formula?

Comment: The case of $\Bbb N$ is a separate question, and I'm pretty sure that it was asked several times before.

Comment: i know the proof for N , but i thought i could prove it for N as sub structure of <R,+,0> . but now i realized it's not possible because of quantifiers

Comment: Could you prove it for $\{0\}$ as a substructure of $\langle\mathbb R,+,0\rangle$?

Comment: no.. i don't get why should i do that?

Comment: The point is that just because something holds for a structure does not mean it holds for a substructure.

Comment: yes, i got it just after asking...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $x\mapsto -x$ is both an automorphism and an order-reversing function.

But I guess your professor instead thought about taking a Hamel basis for $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$, then any permutation of this basis induces an automorphism of the structure, since it is an automorphism of the abelian group. So by switching just two basis elements, we necessarily *don't* preserve the usual ordering on $\Bbb R$.

(Or maybe he meant the first suggestion, by wanting you to note that $x\mapsto qx$ is an automorphism when $q\in\Bbb Q\setminus\{0\}$, and then consider $q=-1$, I can't quite know since I'm not your professor...)